# Decrypting PEM certificates in Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, x509

I am trying to decrypt PEM certificates in Python. At the moment I am trying to use Cryptography x509 to try to achieve this. This was advised to me by my supervisor, however, as he is currently unavailable, I have no chance to ask him.

What I currently have is this:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import json

def uitlezen(message):
    c = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(message.read(), default_backend())
    print(c)
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    en_cert = json.loads("example PEM")
    de_cert = uitlezen(en_cert)
    print(de_cert)
```

(There is a reason why it activates as this is part of a bigger script).
This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 11, in <module>
    en_cert = json.loads("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDBj08sp5++4anGcmQxJjAkBgNVBAoTHVByb2dyZXNzIFNvZnR3YXJlIENvcnBvcmF0aW9uMSAwHgYDVQQDDBcqLmF3cy10ZXN0LnByb2dyZXNzLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD...bml6YXRpb252YWxzaGEyZzIuY3JsMIGgBggrBgEFBQcBAQSBkzCBkDBNBggrBgEFBQcwAoZBaHR0cDovL3NlY3VyZS5nbG9iYWxzaWduLmNvbS9jYWNlcnQvZ3Nvcmdhz3P668YfhUbKdRF6S42Cg6zn-----END PRIVATE KEY-----")
  File "path", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "path", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "path", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have already tried the same thing, except having en_cert (and therefor the example certificate) as a string, like so:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import json

def uitlezen(message):
    c = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(message.read(), default_backend())
    print(c)
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    en_cert = "example PEM" 
    de_cert = uitlezen(en_cert)
    print(de_cert)
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 12, in <module>
    de_cert = uitlezen(en_cert)
  File "path", line 6, in uitlezen
    c = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(message.read(), default_backend())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Does anyone know how I should pass the example PEM so it gets decrypted?

Comment: Look at a PEM certificate, is it [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)?

Comment: Do you mean that a PEM certificate can't be JSON? I had found an example of a certificate in JSON, which is one of the variables I had been trying it with. Would I have to get JSON input (because I do get the input in JSON due to it being an alert through a webhook) and transform it into a different type before I can use this method?

Comment: A PEM key is never JSON but like any other data can be embedded into a JSON structure. (not in your case)

Comment: The thing you're loading with `json.loads()` is obviously not JSON. So why are are trying to pass it through `json.loads()`? The second example gets you closer, but what you have is a private key and your trying to load it using a method for public keys. See [key loading](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-loading).

Comment: I am using json.loads() because I am using sample right now. Normally it would come in through a webhook and as JSON payload. I'll look into key loading though, because indeed, the example used private keys. Thanks

Comment: @student, If you inspect your `json.loads()`, the contents are definitely not a JSON and python is screaming the same thing. PEM is a different encoding format. What you get as part of a webhook will most likely be a JSON format but that payload isn't fed directly. A field or something might be extracted from it and then fed into the certficate decoder or whatever you are trying to write.